# Failed to acces a JSON item

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm completely green in terms of processing or even making HTML requests, so I guess my problem will seem rather trivial, but I did some research and yet I can't find the answer to why isn't my code working.

I make a simple request to AccuWeather API, using their temporary access key - response text seems to be fine and it can be displayed correctly. But then, I'm trying to access a specified item in my response and browser (latest stable Chrome) returns *undefined* in console every time I try to read it's value. Here are my scripts for making and parsing request:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest;
    function request()
            {

                r.open("GET","http://apidev.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/273125.json?language=pl&apikey=hoArfRosT1215",true);
                r.send(null);
                r.onreadystatechange = pr;


            }
    function pr()
            {
                if(r.readyState == 4)
                    {
                        if(r.status==200)
                                {
                                    console.log("pr() function has been called");
                                    var myObj, myJSON, text, obj;
                                    myObj = r.responseText;
                                    obj=JSON.parse(myObj);
                                    console.log(obj.WeatherText);

                                }
                    }
            }
```

I assume I'm doing something wrong while parsing the request, so browser can't access that item correctly, but I have no idea what's wrong. Could anybody show me the right way to access certain items in my case?

PS. Response text can be found by navigating to the address used to make my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that accu weather sends back a data structure of an array. So you need to access obj[index].WeatherText for its value. Its best to add an length check even if you know there will always be one answer. Below is the updated code with some html to help test it out.

```js
var r = new XMLHttpRequest;
function request()
            {

                r.open("GET","http://apidev.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/273125.json?language=pl&apikey=hoArfRosT1215",true);
                r.send(null);
                r.onreadystatechange = pr;


            }
    function pr()
            {
                if(r.readyState == 4)
                    {
                        if(r.status==200)
                                {
                                    console.log("pr() function has been called");
                                    
                                    var myObj, myJSON, text, obj;
                                    myObj = r.responseText;
                                    obj=JSON.parse(myObj);
                                    if(obj.length > 0){
                                      for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { 
    console.log('Weather text = ' + obj[i].WeatherText);
}  
                                    }
                                    

                                }
                    }
            }
```

```html
<button onclick='request()'>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `obj[0].WeatherText` instead of `obj.WeatherText`

```
function request() {
  r.open("GET", "http://apidev.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/273125.json?language=pl&apikey=hoArfRosT1215", true);
  r.send(null);
  r.onreadystatechange = pr;
}

function pr() {
  if (r.readyState == 4) {
    if (r.status == 200) {
      console.log("pr() function has been called");
      var myObj, myJSON, text, obj;
      myObj = r.responseText;
      obj = JSON.parse(myObj);
      console.log(obj[0].WeatherText);
    }
  }
}
```

may be it should help you

Comment: It doesn't - like I said both request and response is fine, my problem lays in accesing certain items of the response.

Answer (score 0):

obj.WeatherText is undefined yes, you need to say obj[0].WeatherText, the results come back as an array....see this:

```js
var r = new XMLHttpRequest;
    function request()
            {

                r.open("GET","http://apidev.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/273125.json?language=pl&apikey=hoArfRosT1215",true);
                r.send(null);
                r.onreadystatechange = pr;


            }
    function pr()
            {
                if(r.readyState == 4)
                    {
                        if(r.status==200)
                                {
                                    console.log("pr() function has been called");
                                    var myObj, myJSON, text, obj;
                                    myObj = r.responseText;
                                    obj=JSON.parse(myObj);
                                    console.log(obj);
                                     console.log(obj[0].WeatherText);
                                    console.log(obj.WeatherText);

                                }
                    }
            }
            
            request();
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works fine. But why do I have to access my object the way I access array's items? Isn't it just one object with a few values instead of 1-element array?

Comment: because data response as a array u note response data structure like that `[{ }]` that the structure of array !

Comment: Thank's, that's all I wanted to know.